# Div height in IE8 compatibility mode

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I have given a div height of 150px. The height is not shown in IE8 compatibility view. Please find the URL of the page below. The css class name is MenuList.
[Test](http://shivanand.in/temp/test.html)

Comment: You're using a huge amount of divs, it wouldn't surprise me if this was part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The div is being shown with the correct height, however the bottom half is not visible because other divs have been positioned over it.

You can verify this by using the F12 tool in IE and clicking it.

Perhaps you can change the z-order to bring it forward. I would still consider rewriting it to use less divs though.

Answer (score 0):

It's got to do with the `position:absolute;`.
Try using F12 and inspect that div, and turn off the `position: absolute;` style - you'll see the parent expand.

Comment: This would make you think setting the z-order to 9999 would fix it.

Comment: I make no claim that z-index might solve anything. Are you saying that you tried disabling the style using F12 (Developer Tools) and it didn't stop hiding the div's bottom part?

Comment: Your .total div has fixed width: why not taking the position: absolute from the child, and make it have left-margin instead?

Comment: Tried giving left margin and removing absolute position. The div is showing the height but not displaying over the below divs. Instead it is pushing them below it.

Comment: Yes, it does. I thought that was what you wished to do - my bad, I **completely** misunderstood.  
Sorry, I don't know how to help you. It's just there, but under the rest. At least you have a pointer to why it's being hidden. =|